# Error al convertir string a JSON en PHP

Tags: php, json

Quisiera saber si me puede dar un poco de luz con la lectura de JSON en PHP. 
Verificando documentación me encontré con `json_decode`, pero solo logro imprimir los valores que no están dentro de un arreglo.

Por ejemplo:

```
$read = new json_file_decode();
$json = $read->json("urlxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"); 

echo "<P><h4>Total preguntas:" .$json["total"];  
echo "<P><h4>preguntas:" .$json["questions"];
```

El JSON que obtengo es el siguiente:

```
{"total":0,"limit":50,"questions":[],"filters":{"limit":50,"offset":0,"is_admin":false,"sorts":[],"caller":507936637,"seller":507936637},"available_filters":[{"id":"item","name":"Item","type":"text"},{"id":"from","name":"From user id","type":"number"},{"id":"totalDivisions","name":"total divisions","type":"number"},{"id":"division","name":"Division","type":"number"},{"id":"status","name":"Status","type":"text","values":["ANSWERED","BANNED","CLOSED_UNANSWERED","DELETED","DISABLED","UNANSWERED","UNDER_REVIEW"]}],"available_sorts":["item_id","from_id","date_created","seller_id"]}
```

Y esto es el resultado:

```
respuesta: Total preguntas:0

> Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\preguntas.php on line 61

preguntas:Array
```

Como ven solo puedo imprimir el total ya que me dice que `questions` esta dentro de un arreglo. ¿Cómo puedo hacer para leer el valor del JSON en PHP?

Caballeros .
les comento,con ayuda de sus comentarios  ya tengo un resultado un poco mas favorable, he utilizado foreach de la siguiente forma

foreach ($json["questions"] as $dir => $dats) {

```
 foreach ($dats as $indice => $valor) {

   ?> <tr> <td> <h5><?php print_r ($valor);
 }
```

}

pasando el foreach ($dats as $indice => $valor) limpie un poco el codigo

la respuesta es esta

Array ( [text] => Discupa ya se vendio voy a eliminar la publicacion [status] => ACTIVE [date_created] => 2019-12-02T18:09:04.051-04:00 )
Array ( [id] => xxxxxxxx [answered_questions] => 1 )
2019-12-29T19:44:47.000-04:00
xxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxx
CLOSED_UNANSWERED
aun disponible
xxxxxxxxxxxx

Comment: Allí dice que estas concatenando o uniendo un array con un string. Pará eso debes recorrer el array con un bucle.  $json["questons"] es un array.

Comment: El problema es al escribir. Estás haciendo `echo "<P><h4>preguntas:" .$json["questions"];` pero `$json["questions"]` es un array y no se puede utilizar `echo`. Debes usar algo como `var_dump`  o `print_r` o similar.

Comment: En el ejemplo que das `questions` es un arreglo vacío!. Considera la función `empty()`para evaluarlo.

Answer (score 2):

Para leer JSON en PHP es muy simple. Hay dos cosas importantes que es necesario saber:

1. `json_decode` admite un segundo parámetro opcional, el cual cuando le pasas `true`, te convierte el JSON a array. En ese caso, la lectura tendría que ser con esta notación: `$objeto["clave"]`. Si no le pasas `true`, te deja un JSON como tal, y en ese caso la lectura se hace con esta notación: `$objeto->clave`, es más intuitiva, más clara, más moderna y más elegante.
2. Los JSON se leen según la estructura que tengan. Por ejemplo, si te interesa leer `question` y lo que hay dentro de esa clave es un array (en JSON los array son identificados por esto `[]`, entonces puedes usar cualquier código válido para leer arrays del lenguaje que estés usando: bucle `foreach`, ciclo `while`, etc. También puedes acceder a los valores directamente por su índice en el caso de arrays. Una problema en tu caso es que `questions` es un array vacío según los datos que muestras. Para la prueba de más abajo he metido dos objetos json dentro de `question`. Si los array se identifican por `[]`, los objetos json se identifican por esto `{}`.

Con esas dos claves, ya no tendrás mayores problemas para leer los datos.

Veamos un ejemplo:

## Datos recibidos

```
$data='
{
   "total":0,
   "limit":50,
   "questions":[
      {
         "id":1,
         "title":"This is question 1"
      },
      {
         "id":2,
         "title":"This is question 2"
      }
   ],
   "filters":{
      "limit":50,
      "offset":0,
      "is_admin":false,
      "sorts":[

      ],
      "caller":507936637,
      "seller":507936637
   },
   "available_filters":[
      {
         "id":"item",
         "name":"Item",
         "type":"text"
      },
      {
         "id":"from",
         "name":"From user id",
         "type":"number"
      },
      {
         "id":"totalDivisions",
         "name":"total divisions",
         "type":"number"
      },
      {
         "id":"division",
         "name":"Division",
         "type":"number"
      },
      {
         "id":"status",
         "name":"Status",
         "type":"text",
         "values":[
            "ANSWERED",
            "BANNED",
            "CLOSED_UNANSWERED",
            "DELETED",
            "DISABLED",
            "UNANSWERED",
            "UNDER_REVIEW"
         ]
      }
   ],
   "available_sorts":[
      "item_id",
      "from_id",
      "date_created",
      "seller_id"
   ]
}
';
```

## Lectura como objeto JSON

```
#Creamos el json como objeto, no como array, por eso no ponemos true
$json=json_decode($data);
#Aquí accedemos a todo lo que hay en la clave questions del objeto
#que en este caso es un array
$questions=$json->questions;
#Como es un array, lo podemos leer usando un bucle
foreach ($questions as $q){
    #Observa la notación usada: $q-clave para sacar los datos
    echo "$q->id : $q->title".PHP_EOL;
}
```

**Salida:**

```
1 : This is question 1
2 : This is question 2
```

Asi, puedes leer cualquier otra parte del JSON. Por ejemplo, si quieres el valor de `limit`, que está en la raíz del objeto en sí:

```
echo $json->limit;
```

**Salida:**

```
50
```

O, si quieres acceder a lo que hay en `filters`:

```
$filters=$json->filters;
var_dump($filters);
```

**Salida:**

```
object(stdClass)#4 (6) {
  ["limit"]=>
  int(50)
  ["offset"]=>
  int(0)
  ["is_admin"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["sorts"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["caller"]=>
  int(507936637)
  ["seller"]=>
  int(507936637)
}
```

Y así sucesivamente.

## Lectura como array

La lectura como array puede ser interesante en ciertos contextos. Supongamos que necesitas mostrar las claves y los valores en elementos dispares que pueden tener claves distintas, o son muchas claves y no quieres acceder a ellas por su nombre. Entonces lo conviertes como array y aplicas una lectura del tipo `foreach ($objeto as $k=>$v) { ... }`. Esto no se puede hacer con un objeto JSON, pero sí con un array.

Veamos un ejemplo:

```
#Pasamos true para que nos de el objeto como array
$arr=json_decode($data,true);
#Observa ahora la notación que se usa
$questions=$arr["questions"];

foreach ($questions as $question){
    foreach ($question as $k=>$v){
    echo "$k: $v ";
    }
    echo PHP_EOL;
}
```

**Salida:**

```
id: 1 title: This is question 1 
id: 2 title: This is question 2
```

Aquí se obtuvo cada clave/valor sin necesidad de mencionarlas de forma explícita dentro del `foreach`.

Answer (score 1):

La variable `$json['questions']` no esta dentro de un arreglo, sino que es un arreglo, por lo tanto no lo puedes desplegar con `echo`.  Necesitas un `foreach()` asi:

```
$read = new json_file_decode();
$json = $read->json("urlxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"); 

echo "<P><h4>Total preguntas:" .$json["total"];  
echo "<P><h4>preguntas:"; 
foreach($json["questions"] as $question) {
    echo $question;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema es al escribir el valor porque `$json["questions"]` es un array y no se puede usar con [`echo`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php), que solo funciona con cadenas como se especifica en la documentación (resaltado por mí):

> echo — **Muestra una o más cadenas**
>
> Descripción
>
> ```
> echo ( string $arg1 [, string $... ] ) : void
> ```

Para imprimir un array debes usar otras funciones como [`var_dump`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.var-dump.php)  o [`print_r`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.print-r.php) o similar. Por ejemplo:

```
print_r($json["questions"]);
```